# Detecting anomalies from time series correlated variables

Tags: machine-learning, python

I have a daily set of data that I need to detect if there are any anomalies in it. These are variables related to the stock market so I'd just give an example (totally fictitious) here:

```
Date     Type  Notional Underlying Expiry Market_Value DV01 X    Y    Z
1/1/2018 Bonds 100,000  USTreasury Mar18  100,000      2.5  2.5  5.0 15.0
1/2/2018 Bonds 150,000  USTreasury Mar18  149,000      4.0  4.0  8.0 12.0
```

What I'm trying to say is that there're some unknown correlations a,b,c between DV01 and parameters X, Y and Z. However I'm not entirely sure what the relation is, for simplicity sake I'm just letting a=1, b=2, c=3. For other type of instruments such as Options, the correlations will be entirely different. What I hope to achieve here is to be able to pick out values which do not conform to these relations. If the following data comes in the next day, the 50.0 in Z should be flagged.

```
Date     Type  Notional Underlying Expiry Market_Value DV01 X    Y    Z
1/3/2018 Bonds 200,000  USTreasury Mar18  200,500      5.5  5.5  11.0 50.0
```

Unfortunately a,b,c are not constants; they change with time. The model should be able to learn from the past, say 10 days, and establish what type of relation it is and check the next day if there're any anomalies. What would be a good way to start?

Comment: If I understood you correctly you are looking for an incremental learning algorithm for multivariate time series classification. I do not know any exact papers which will fit your problem, but there is plenty of literature out there.